# Custom Tab Bar Controller Problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue

Currently in my project, I made a custom tab bar controller to achieve vertical tab bar effect just like the standard tab bar controller. In the custom tab bar, I have two buttons linked with custom segue to two view controllers. What this custom segue does is to replace the subview inside my custom tab bar controller with the two view controllers.

After I've done this, my custom tab bar controller works fine when switching between the two buttons. However, when I try to place a button onto one of the view controllers and add a modal segue from the button to a brand new view controller, problem happens. When I pressed the button, the program crashes.

I'm thinking the problem might be the view controller hierarchy problem. On the other hand, I created a new project with same storyboard structure and custom segue, this time, when I place a button in one of the view controller and connects using a modal segue to a new view controller, it works, but with a warning saying "Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged".

I'm very confused right now. Could someone point me to the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

---

Maybe this won't help that much, but this is one way to do it if you were doing this programmatically, which you may be able to interpret this answer to Storyboards:

```
-(void)dismiss
{
    [[self navigationController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
}

-(void)showModal
{
    NewCustomViewController * pvc = [NewCustomViewController new];
    CustomNavigationController * ffs = [[CustomNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:pvc];
    [ffs setNavigationBarHidden:TRUE];
    UIBarButtonItem * backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"exit-button"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(dismiss)];
    [[pvc navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:backBarButtonItem];
    [[self navigationController] presentViewController:ffs animated:true completion:nil];
}
```

I've created my own UITabBarController in the past and successfully used this same method for modal presentation from the custom UITabBarController subclass, try it out, I know it's not storyboards, but it's similar. In fact, let me change something to make this easier for you.

Also, do you have your viewcontrollers nested inside navigationControllers in the custaom tabbar?

should be like this

```
UItabbarcontroller
   navigationcontroller
       viewcontroller
   navigationcontroller
       viewcontroller

this works the easiest, also, could be even better like this:

navigationController <== mainscreen rootViewController as a navigationController in the AppDelegate
   UItabbarcontroller
      navigationcontroller
          viewcontroller
      navigationcontroller
          viewcontroller
```

Now, you say the tabbar isn't nested inside a navigationcontroller right? so we are talking about this:

should be like this

```
UItabbarcontroller
   navigationcontroller
       viewcontroller
   navigationcontroller
       viewcontroller
```

The problem with this is the fact that if I call a modal from the UItabbarcontroller subclass and do a :

```
    self.navigationController present XXX etc. etc,
```

then this is going to fail, more than likely since the tabbarcontroler doesnt have a navigationController

Also if you call segue navigation with a navigation controller from one of the veiwcontrollrs and you try to self.navigationctonroller present, then you have the same issue, there's no navigaitoncontroller.

You an try to present modal from

```
  [self present ... blah blah
```

but doing this wont allow user interaction from the presented modal since it wasn't presented in a navigation controller, I would smash your TabbarViewcontroller into a navigationcontroller, it shouldn't be that hard and then I'd root your viewcontrollers in your tabbar in a Navigationcontroller first and then try out those buttons again, that's just three additional navigationcontrollers, no big deal

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm still quite confused. For your question, my tab bar view controllers don't nest inside navigation controllers

Comment: A ha!, okay, this makes it complicated then. So, it's not hard to nest the tabbar controller in a navigation controller, and I'd suggest this becuase of this, read my answer again in a second

Comment: Thanks again for the well written comment! So basically what I should try now is to embed my tab bar controller and two of my view controllers into navigation controller and then follow the regular approach.

Comment: Currently, I'm using the following code to replace the subview in the root view controller (where tab bar lives) with the view controllers:     tabBarController.currentViewController = destViewController;
    [tabBarController.placeholder addSubview:destViewController.view];

Comment: yep, show it in your question, ill see if i can help

Comment: so now, instead, I should make my custom segue connects to the embedded navigation view controller in order to work

Comment: I'd love it if that worked, but it might be something crazier than that depending no what you did in your code, I'm just saying it makes the navigation difficult when you don't rely on navigation controllers as the navigation source, but this may not be the answer, depends on what your code is

Comment: cool, I will give a try and see if any further problems come up. Thanks a lot for the help!!